# Is there anyway to select image from external storage SD card in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, imagepicker

I am using Nativescript imagepicker plugin for selecting images in android, the plugin works good when selecting images from internal storage but when selecting from external storage SD card it returns empty string, i searched everywhere for a solution, workaround or even another plugin but still no luck. Is there anyway to select images from external storage SD card in Nativescript?

```
selectImage() {
        let that = this;
    
        let context = imagepicker.create({
            mode: "single" // use "multiple" for multiple selection
        });
    
        context
            .authorize()
            .then(function () {                    
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(function (selection) {
                if (imageNumber == 1)
                    that.imageOneSrc = selection.length > 0 ? selection[0]['_android'] : "~/app/images/camera.png";
                
                selection.forEach(function (element) {
                    element.options.width = that.secondaryImageWidth;
                    element.options.height = that.secondaryImageHeight;
                });
    
            }).catch(function (e) {
                // process error                    
                    that.imageOneSrc = "~/app/images/camera.png";                    
            });
    }
```